# Как настроить сервер на отправку данных на андроид устройство?

Tags: android, sql-server, сервер

Я новичок в андроид, много гуглил прoблему, но так и не смог понять каким образом настроить сервер на отправку данных. Очень прошу помочь мне, дать ссылку на какие-либо ресурсы или подсказать.

Answer (score 2):

я не андроид разработчик, но я думаю у вас должно быть наоборот

1. приложение должно запрашивать данные с сервера, а не сервер
2. Поднимаешь бэк приложение, делаешь апи.
3. на телефоне обращаешься к апи

Я бы вам рекомендовал изучить

- http протоколы (есть и другие, но для начала сойдет)
- как взаимодействуют различные приложения

Есть различные фреймворки для написания бэк приложений. Зависит от языка программирования

- Spring Framework + Spring boot для Java
- Laravel/Lumen - для PHP
- ExpressJs - для JS

Comment: Спасибо большое!